# swift: firebase putData and downloadUrl returns URL late - too late

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In short, I am writing an App with the following order.

1. Upload an image to Firebase Storage.
2. Download the image URL.
3. Upload the URL (and some other staff) to Firestore documents.

Parts 1 and 3 are working well. Beside the fact that I receive the URL too late. Yes too late.

To understand what's happening I added print statements in the expected order 0-13. See my code below. Print statements 9-13 are outside the function uploadImage.

When executing the app the processed order is the following:

0 - before calling function uploadImage

1 - Right before putData

8 - Before leaving function uploadImage

12 - Upload document with URL: Optional("")

13 - At FirestoreDB.collection.addDocument ->Document added with ID: 3uDhNM3o…

2 - Processing the completion of putData

4 - Right before downloadURL

5 - Processing the completion of downloadURL

7 - Within completion url https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/…

10 - Within clompetion url of uploadImage function

11a - URL available https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/…

Any advice?
Thanks, Michael

```
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        let uploadStorageReference = storageReference.child(directory)
        let imgID = NSUUID().uuidString
        let idStorageReference = uploadStorageReference.child(imgID)
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        print("1 - Right before putData")
        _ = idStorageReference.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            print("2 - Processing the completion of putData")
            if let error = error {
                print("3 - Within error handling of putData \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil)
                return
            } else {
                print("4 - Right before downloadURL")
                idStorageReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    print("5 - Processing the completion of downloadURL")
                    if let error = error {
                        print("6 - Within error handling of downloadURL \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        completion(nil)
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let downloadedURL = url {
                            print("7 - Within completion url \(downloadedURL)")
                            completion(downloadedURL)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        print("8 - Before leaving function uploadImage")
    }
```

Comment: The order doesn't seem strange to me. You are seeing the concept of asynchronism. Look how to manage it. It's normal that 8 is printed just after 1.

Answer (score 0):

As [Larme mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711529/swift-firebase-putdata-and-downloadurl-returns-url-late-too-late/57721806#comment101866012_57711529):

> The order doesn't seem strange to me. You are seeing the concept of asynchronism. Look how to manage it. It's normal that 8 is printed just after 1.

I fixed it by using DispatchSemaphore.